# ManyToManyField is empty in post_save() function

Tags: python, django

When a new record is added to a table, I have to execute a SQL statement on an external database. This query includes the use of a ManyToManyField. So I just connected the function like this:

```
post_save.connect(post_save_mymodel, sender=MyModel)
```

And in my post_save_mymodel() function, here is what I do:

```
def post_save_mymodel(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for e in instance.my_m2mfield.all():
            # Query including "e".
```

But, too bad, instance.my_m2mfield.all() is always empty! Even though they should contain some elements! I tried to get the new element by doing

```
new_element = MyModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
```

but it doesn't change anything, I've still got the same issue...

Wny help/advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you first save your instance and after that you add m2m relations to it. This is how ManyToMany fields work in Django data models. Django needs to know the ID of the items that should be connected with m2m relations.

I think that your code looks like this:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(some_field=some_value)  # post save signal triggered here
instance.my_m2mfield = my_set_of_m2m_models
```

You need to connect your handler to the `django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed` signal. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed). For example:

```
def post_save_mymodel(sender, instance, action, reverse, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' and not reverse:
        for e in instance.my_m2mfield.all():
            # Query including "e"
m2m_changed.connect(post_save_mymodel, sender=MyModel.my_m2mfield.through)
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly. So I assume it is necessary to precise the attribute, for the signal to be called at the right time? Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is a devil in the details.  The post_save_model handler is not called with action set to 'post_add' if the contents of the m2m field are cleared.  You might want to detect that event.  There is a 'post_clear" action but, unfortunately, Django seems to clear m2m fields before changing them so the 'post_clear' event is generated during changes to the m2m field as well as when it is cleared.

Comment: @Deneuve, What does 'precise the attribute' mean?