# Django post_save signal + ManyToManyField: more questions

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I tried to connect a handler to model's post_save signal I have found that model's ManyToMany field is empty at that moment. I have googled and found a solution here: [ManyToManyField is empty in post_save() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898829/manytomanyfield-is-empty-in-post-save-function)
The solution was to connect to `m2m_changed signal` of the model.
However I still have some questions.

**How to precisely detect if model instance was created and not updated**

In the answer there was a condition:

```py
if action == 'post_add' and not reverse:
```

But it seems to be not working when I am editing the instance in admin interface (seems like m2m field being touched when I am clicking "Save" button in admin).

I have discovered one way to do it via assigning instance attribute in `post_save` handler
and checking for it in `m2m_changed` handler.

```py
def on_m2m_changed(sender, instance, action, reverse, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == "post_add" and not reverse and instance.just_created:
        # do stuff

def on_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.just_created = created
```

But for me it looks bad and I am not sure that it is the correct way to do that. Is there another way to do it?

**What to do if we have multiple m2m fields in the model?**

Is order of updating m2m fields of the model well-defined and can we rely on it? Or we should connect to each m2m_changed handler and manipulate flags/counters in instance? BTW, can we rely on the fact that `m2m_changed` is executed after `post_save`

**May be there is another way to handle complete save of the instance with all its m2m fields?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this problem too. Apparently this was a bug (7 years old) and was fixed 3 months ago:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6707

This might also interests you, in this ticket one of the core developers says this works as intended and won't fix it:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13022